# "icon dimensions (60 * 60) don't meet the size requirement" in submitting my app to app store

Tags: ios, icons, ios7

In submitting my iOS7 app to apple store, I got the error message "icon dimensions (60 * 60) don't meet the size requirement, the icon file must be 57 * 57 pixels, in .png format".  Because my app only targets to ios7, 60*60 icon should be correct.

I used asset catalog to manage the icons.  I have 60 * 60 pixel icons, but not 57*57 pixel icons there.

My project builds fine for test flight, the above error only occurs when submitting to apple store.  Completely lost, any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be 120 x 120 pixels, meaning 60 x 60 points on a retina display.

Comment: please see the whole message in my above post.  It says the correct file "must be 57 * 57 pixels".

Comment: Are you sure your app's *Deployment Target* is iOS 7, and not just the *Base SDK*? You would see the app's deployment target in the *General* tag, under *Deployment Info*.

Comment: :Deployment target: 7.0. "   yes,  I was also suspicious of my setting deployment target is not right.  Where else should I check if my target is correctly set?